# SIGSEGV at JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, awt, multiple-monitors

I wrote a litte program, that may show a message dialog:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My message", "My title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

If I start this from console it crashes with a segmentation fault. I tried Java 1.6 and 1.7 (there is no newer version available here), I work at a Unix workstation with dual monitor setup.

This is the stacktrace:

```
Stack: [0xb4f30000,0xb4fb0000],  sp=0xb4faf3a8,  free space=508k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0xb4ae38a8
j  sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.getXineramaCenterPoint()Ljava/awt/Point;+1237795392
j  sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.getXineramaCenterPoint()Ljava/awt/Point;+0
j  sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint()Ljava/awt/Point;+7
j  java.awt.Window.setLocationRelativeTo(Ljava/awt/Component;)V+94
j  javax.swing.JOptionPane.initDialog(Ljavax/swing/JDialog;ILjava/awt/Component;)V+77
j  javax.swing.JOptionPane.createDialog(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljavax/swing/JDialog;+74
j  javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;IILjavax/swing/Icon;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)I+58
j  javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;ILjavax/swing/Icon;)V+9
j  javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;I)V+5
```

How can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: What windows manager are you using ? Java < 7 tend to be pretty lame at handling non-reparenting WMs

Comment: I actually don't know. I guess X11. It's SunOS with running KDE desktop environment. How can I find out?

Comment: KDE, that's what I wanted to know. That's not the easy explaination I thought about, sorry